# How can I get past this 'SSL connect error' when using jsonlite::fromJSON in R?

Tags: r, ssl, connection, rcurl, jsonlite

## Issue

I get the following error whenever I run

```
all_companies <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https://www.sec.gov/files/company_tickers_exchange.json")
```

```
Warning: URL 'https://www.sec.gov/files/company_tickers_exchange.json': status was 'SSL connect error'Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
  cannot open the connection to 'https://www.sec.gov/files/company_tickers_exchange.json'
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

## What I've tried

I am trying to run this on a new work computer, it runs fine on my old work computer but the new one gives me this error.

- It seems the difference causing this issue is that I am using {jsonlite} 1.8.2 on my new computer and 1.8.0 on my old computer. Deep in the definition of the `fromJSON()` function, the working version seems to use `curl::curl()` to establish a connection whereas the not-working version uses `base::url()`.
- The following example line from the help documentation runs fine on the new computer with version 1.8.2

```
data1 <- fromJSON("https://api.github.com/users/hadley/orgs")
```

- I can access the JSON file I am trying to read on an internet browser.
- I do not have permission to install Rtools on my computer to be able to compile an older version of {jsonlite}.

Comment: I can run the command just fine on my computer, so I can't help diagnose your issue. Why don't you download the file first and then parse it afterwards? Within R you can use `download.file`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Looks like I'm having a similar issue with trying to download it. I tried the following:

`# Create temporary directory
temp_dir <- tempdir()

# Get all company ciks
all_companies <- download.file("https://www.sec.gov/files/company_tickers_exchange.json",
                               destfile = paste0(temp_dir, "\\", "all_companies.json"),
                               method = "libcurl")`
`Error in download.file("{link above}",  : 
  cannot open URL
In addition: Warning message: status was 'SSL connect error'`